# Displaying multiple values linked list

Tags: c++, string, struct, linked-list, nodes

I'm new to C++ and currently experimenting about linked lists and I'm having trouble with displaying the multiple values in my program. I know the problem is somewhere in the pointers(DisplayAll function) but I'm not sure how to solve it.

```
node* InfoBook::AddNode(nodePtr temp)
{ 
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string phonenumber;
    string dayofbirth;
    string monthofbirth;
    string yearofbirth;
    string age;
    string streetname;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
    InfoBook ad;

       if(head != NULL)
        {
            current = head;
            while(current -> next != NULL)
            {
                current = current -> next;
            }
            current -> next = new node;
            current -> firstname = temp -> firstname;
            current -> lastname = temp -> lastname;
                     ////code here to add the other values////
            current -> zipcode = temp -> zipcode;
            current -> next -> next = nullptr;
            return current;
            ad.userPromptStatement();
        }
       else
        {
            head = new node;
            head -> firstname = temp -> firstname;
            head -> lastname = temp -> lastname;
                    ////code here to add the other values////
            head -> zipcode = temp -> zipcode;
            head -> next = nullptr;
            return current;
        }
}

////////////////////////////////DisplayAll/////////////////////////////////

void InfoBook::DisplayAll()
{
    current = head;
    int count = 1;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string phonenumber;
    string dayofbirth;
    string monthofbirth;
    string yearofbirth;
    string age;
    string streetname;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;

        if(current == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "\n\n\No Record exists.";
        }
            while(current != NULL)
            {      ////////I know the problem is somewhere between here////////
                cout << "Record # " << count << " : ";
                cout << current -> firstname << endl;
                cout << current -> lastname << endl;
                cout << current -> phonenumber << endl;
                cout << current -> dayofbirth << endl;
                cout << current -> monthofbirth << endl;
                cout << current -> yearofbirth << endl;
                cout << current -> age << endl;
                cout << current -> streetname << endl;
                cout << current -> city << endl;
                cout << current -> state << endl;
                cout << current -> zipcode << endl;
                cout <<"\n\n\n";
                current = current -> next;
                count++;
            }
}
                        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

////pointers

InfoBook::InfoBook()
{

```
head = NULL;
current = NULL;
temp = NULL;
```

}

////////

```
class InfoBook
{
private:
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr current;
    nodePtr temp;

public:
    InfoBook();

    void userPromptStatement();
    node* AddNode(nodePtr);
    void DisplayAll();
```

/////////////

```
typedef struct node
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string phonenumber;
    string dayofbirth;
    string monthofbirth;
    string yearofbirth;
    string age;
    string streetname;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;
    static int count;
    node* next;
} *nodePtr;
```

the program displays only 'Record # :'s but not the values.  Any ideas?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

i think after

```
current -> next = new node;
```

you should add this:

```
current = current->next;
```

because you have to assign to the node you've alloc, not the current one.

Comment: Also, you can have a look at: http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/data-structures-singly-linked-list-with-c-program-source-code

Comment: this is likely correct, though the last thing in this list, `current -> next -> next = nullptr;` should have one `next` dropped out to avoid invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: edit current -> next -> next = nullptr; to current -> next = nullptr;

then, in else, you should return head, not current. Because if head==null, you don't do anything with current